# How can I dynamically change the price of a Product based on the amount of characters entered into a Custom Field by a Shopper?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am currently working on a WordPress website, with WooCommerce functionality.  On the Product Page, I have created a Custom Field, which allows shoppers to enter a piece of text that they would like to appear on the associated product.

Each product has a starting price with my client wanting to then charge the shopper an additional fee of (for example) £1 per letter entered into the Custom Field.

My client would then like the Product Price, on the Product Page, to change in real time to reflect the amount of letters entered.  For example:

> Product A:  £20
>
> As shopper enters 5 letters, the Product Price changes to £25 in real
>   time.

So far, I have created the Character Counter on the Product Page, using the following code:

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);
jQuery(document).on('keydown', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = jQuery(this).val().length;
    jQuery('#character_count').text(cs);
}
</script>
```

At present, I am Outputting this Character Counter through the use of the below code in the `functions.php` file:

**Code Entered into functions.php file:**

```
function custom_character_counter(){
    echo 'Letters Entered:  <span id="character_count"></span>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_character_counter');
```

I could be wrong, but I assume I now need to manipulate the product price to reflect the following equation:

```
Original Product Price + (Characters Entered x £1)
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I can achieve this or indeed if there is a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a input hidden to place the price ?

Comment: The current price is being displayed by the default WooCommerce settings.  Do I need to create a hidden input field?

Comment: yes check my answer im posting .. im currently doing it now

Comment: Thank you.  I look forward to your answer being posted here :-)

Comment: I know it may take some time to adjust your codes. but hope atleast it'll helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an input hidden for the product price / price per letter / and new price then do the computation with it .. the new price will be the one to be pass to the form for its total price.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-letters-container">
    <h1>Product 1</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="price" class="product-price" value="20" />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" class="letter-price" value="2" />
    
    <input type="text" name="letters" class="product-custom-text" />
    
    <input type="hidden" name="price" class="product-new-price-hidden" />
    <div class="character_count"></div>
</div>

<div class="custom-letters-container">
    <h1>Product 2</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="price" class="product-price" value="25" />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" class="letter-price" value="5" />
    
    <input type="text" name="letters" class="product-custom-text" />
    
    <input type="hidden" name="price" class="product-new-price-hidden" />
    <div class="character_count"></div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).on('keyup', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);
        jQuery(document).on('keydown', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);
    
        function updateCount() {
            var strlen = jQuery(this).val().length;
            var lettertotal = parseInt(jQuery(this).parent().children('.letter-price').val()) * strlen;
            var totalprice = parseInt(jQuery(this).parent().children('.product-price').val()) + lettertotal;
            jQuery(this).parent().children('.product-new-price-hidden').val(totalprice);
        jQuery(this).parent().children('.character_count').text(totalprice);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As a newbie to jQuery, where would I enter the letter pricing?

Comment: well if you have a database for it you can just call it on the database .. if it fix as £1 , then just put it as a static value = 1

Comment: Is there no way to enter the fixed amount within the above code?

Comment: is your price fixed ? then just include the `<input type="hidden" name="price" class="letter-price" value="1" />` as fixed price per letter

Comment: Ok, I shall try this and see how I get on.  Are you saying that the code you provided, would dynamically change the default WooCommerce price or would it create an additional price text box?  Thanks for your time with this question.

Comment: well if you could include the view of the WooCommerce product list / product order maybe i could help you

Comment: At present, the page is split into 2 columns.  The left side has the Product Image with the right Side having; Product Title, Product Description, Product Price, Custom Box and then the Add to Basket button.  How could I change the Price displayed?  I am not sure what coding I would need to insert.